# How to compute $E[e^{(i-1)Z}]$ where $Z$ is standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, characteristic-functions

Is there a trick on how to compute $$E[e^{(i-1)Z}]$$
where $Z$ is standard normal and $i$ is the imaginary number. 
We know that $E[e^{iZ}]$ is just a characteristic function of $Z$ but this is a little bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate $E[\exp(zZ)]$ for any arbitrary complex number $z$. Note that all odd moments of $Z$ are $0$, while the even moments are given by $E[Z^{2k}] = \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}$. The power series of the exponential function and the dominated convergence theorem yield the following equality:
$$E[\exp(zZ)] = \sum \limits_{l = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{l!} z^l E[Z^l] = \sum \limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2l)!}z^{2k} E[Z^{2k}] = \sum \limits_{k = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^k \frac{1}{k!} = \exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Can this still be done for any $Z$ and not only Gaussian?

Comment: This depends on the distribution of $Z$. For some distributions it works, for some it doesn't. You need to check if you can find an integrable majorant to apply the dominated convergence theorem. One sufficient condition is that $E[\exp(z|Z|)] < \infty$.

Comment: For example, if replace $Z$ by $Z^2$ would it still work?

Comment: This will only work for $|z| < \frac{1}{2}$. But the resulting power series doesn't have a form that can easily be simplified.